# Python get local variable inside function from another script

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I have these scripts with the following contents:

**first.py:**

```
bob = 0

if bob = 0:
    bob + 1
```

**second.py:**

```
from first import bob
print bob
```

How do I get `second.py` to return `1` and not `0`?

Comment: Your question's title is a bit misleading. You don't have any local variables or functions, but rather global variables in two modules.

Comment: @Blckknght edit away!

Comment: OP, did you not get an error when running `second.py`? I'd assume `if bob = 0` would throw a SyntaxError.

Comment: @jmu303: I would, but the wrong wording may be significant to the questioner's misunderstanding of what is going on. Perhaps the code shown is an oversimplified version of what they're really doing, and they do actually have functions and local variables in the real code.

Comment: its working now just a stupid mistake

Comment: yes its a very simplified version

Comment: @Blckknght fair enough.

Comment: the original code has a function not an if statement

Comment: i still cant get it to work on the orginal code.. does anyone want to see it

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax in first.py is wrong and won't do what you want.  One equals sign is used for assignment, not comparison, and you don't actually save the result of adding one to bob in the variable.

```
bob = 0

if bob == 0:
    bob += 1
```